# Any RC4 decryption lib for ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

i found one lib which is here
https://github.com/juggler/ruby-rc4/blob/master/lib/rc4.rb

But its not working for ruby 1.9.x
it throws an error 
undefined method ^' for "\x1A":String__

is there any work around in ruby 1.9.x?

after googling i came to know that "In Ruby 1.9 string[index] returns character not code of the character (like it was in 1.8)." (https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3144-undefined-method-for-string-ror-234)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If that (one operation) is the only problem, couldn't you just modify the library a bit?

Comment: i dont know how this RC4 decryption works. i tried it text[i].ord but still its throwing error .TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String  .

Comment: what line are you getting an error on.  If you are getting that error, you are not dealing with a string, it is a number.  Looking at the code, you only need to change 0.upto(text.length-1) {|i| text[i] = text[i] ^ round}  The initializer is ok for 1.9 as it uses each_byte

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dotemacs/ruby-rc4/tree/master/lib  This guy has forked it, and added some tests. The original is not maintained it looks like. This library is extremely simple and to fix that you just have to use the ord method on String.

```
 s = "foo"
 s[0].ord
```

So clone that guys git, fix it, and send him a pull request, it is the open source way :)  if he does not respond then keep your fork and people will then use that.

EDIT

change line 27 to:

```
  0.upto(text.length-1) {|i| text[i] = [text[i].ord ^round].pack('c')}
```

Comment: The error is gone but its still not working for me . did u try the lib with ruby 1.9.2 . am not able to descrypt the data

Comment: It worked fine for me.  I used the encrypt then the decrypt and it round tripped.

Comment: This fork worked fine for me with Ruby 1.9.3: https://github.com/benolee/ruby-rc4 I forked that to fix an issue where each RC4 instance could only be used once: https://github.com/henrik/ruby-rc4